# Adding an app when building an standalone application in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, exe, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I am creating a stand-alone executable from a MATLAB app, using the MATLAB Compiler. When run the app has a button that calls a script M-file (myfile.m).

MAIN FILE (trail.mlapp). Part of the .mlapp file.

```
function ButtonPushed(app,event)
     run myfile.m
     closereq
end
```

This `myfile.m` also calls an another app in the middle (just another MATLAB app).  For this second app to execute properly (to avoid shadowing), it asked me to create a folder (let's say `X`) and put the app-related files in there.

Now while creating the executable, I am not able to add the folder `X`. Is there anyway to do this?

I looked up in some previous answers, they said:

```
if isdeployed
  fid = fopen(fullfile(ctfroot,'myfolder','myfile.dat'))
end
```

But I don't know where to place this piece of code, whether in `myfile.m` or my main file for which I am creating the executable.

I am calling the second app using this following commands:

```
APPINFO  = matlab.apputil.install('./X/Recomm')
matlab.apputil.run('RecommAPP')
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. You are using the MATLAB Compiler, I think. And you have code in `dir` as well as in `dir/X`. And you want to be able to run the code in `dir/X`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, I am using MATLAB Compiler. In `dir/X` I have app files (which I am calling in `myfile.m`). All the associated files to run the `myfile.m` are in `dir` except the APP files which are in `dir/X`

Comment: I don't have experience with `apputil`, but can't you add `dir/X` to your path, and just run the app by calling it's main function, whatever the name is?

Comment: Also, instead of `run myfile.m`, you should just do `myfile`.

Comment: No, I cannot add it. When I add it, It says shadowing

Comment: What is shadowing and what is being shadowed? Could you give more information? You might need to rename some files in either app, so that they don't share file names.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I changed the file name and the error is as follows
`Function 'X_gui' in the current folder shadows the app entry point. Change the current folder and execute the app again`

Comment: @CrisLuengo This time I didn't package the app, but I defined a public property and called the app directly in my .m file.

That way I avoided the error. Need to see If this works, when I run an executable